# How to display records in SQL Server that have same value in Column 2 but value in Column 1 should not be present in any other record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a below table like this -

```
Policy  Column1  Column2
A         4        100
B         4        100
C         3        100
D         3        100
E         2        100
F         5        100
```

The Output should be

```
Policy Column1 Column 2
E         2      100
F         5      100
```

Can someone please guide me.

Comment: It's not clear what you're after / your  example output seems to contradict your question.  When you say "the same value in column 1"; the same as what?  Similarly, what are you comparing to for the different value in column2?

Comment: Are you after rows where the value in `column1` is unique compared to all other rows' column1 values?

Comment: I've had a go at tidying up the question (I removed the image and formatted the tables), but it isn't clear what logic you are wanting to apply to this. Are you looking for rows where there is only a single instance of the value in `Column1`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're after rows where the value in column1 is unique (i.e. no other row has that same value in column 1)

```
select max(Policy) Policy -- if we're just getting 1 row, the max is the only value
, Column1
, max(Column2) Column2 -- as above
from myTable
group by Column1 -- group by column 1 then
having count(1) = 1 -- count how many rows are in that group; if it's unique we get 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from policies
where Column1 in (select Column1 
  from policies 
  group by Column1 
  having count(*)=1);
```

[DBFiddle demo is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8eaa33641c0eea96fd7c01c3cb5c662a)

Answer (score 0):

You want to divide the data into chunk via `partition by`. Then you can determine which of them has only a single row.

```
with data as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by Column1, Column2) as cnt
    from T
)
select Policy, Column1, Column2 from data where cnt = 1;
```

This kind of query was harder to write twenty years ago. If you're learning SQL I'd encourage you to get a handle on some of the foundational concepts before diving into table expressions and analytic functions.